# Request parameters in spring

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I need to take two parameters in my spring controller.

http://mydomain.com/myapp/getDetails?Id=13&subId=431

I have controller which will return Json for this request.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getDetails", method = RequestMethod.GET,params = "id,subId", produces="application/json")
    @ResponseBody
    public MyBean getsubIds(@RequestParam String id, @RequestParam String subId) {
     return MyBean
  }
```

I am getting 400 for when i tried to invoke the URL. Any thoughts on this?
I was able to get it with one parameter.

Comment: Could it be that you're passing "Id" in your URL yet you specify "id" in the controller? (note lowercase/uppercase first letter)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try specifying which parameter in the query string should match the parameter in the method like so:

```
public MyBean getsubIds(@RequestParam("id") String id, @RequestParam("subId") String subId) {
```

If the code is being compiled without the parameter names, Spring can have trouble figuring out which is which.

Comment: @Adam try removing the `parama` section of the `@RequestMapping`.  I've never needed those before...

Answer (score 1):

As for me it works (by calling: http://www.example.com/getDetails?id=10&subId=15):

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getDetails", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces="application/json")
@ResponseBody
public MyBean getsubIds(@RequestParam("id") String id, @RequestParam("subId") String subId) {
    return new MyBean();
}
```

P.S. Assuming you have class MyBean.